# Preferred way of importing a file: http.get or require()?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

What is the preferred way of importing, for example, a JSON file in a TypeScript project? I have seen the following methods being used:

```
var json_file = require('./file.json')
```

or

```
var file;
this.http.get('./file.json').subscribe(
    next => { file = next; }
)
```

but which of those methods should I actually use? To me it seems more straight forward to just use `require` but then again I see `http.get` more oftenly being used in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If the JSON file is small, and avoiding the asynchronous delay is preferable, go with the first method.

If, however, the JSON file is large, and you can get your web page to open faster and more responsively while waiting for the JSON to be loaded, go with the second.

Comment: Okay, but none is better or preferable in any other terms?

Comment: No one method is simply intrinsically "better" in a general sense, no.

Answer (score 1):

`require` is synchronous. File path can't be truly dynamic (at least with Webpack). The file is bundled with the application and affects initial loading time (possible to address with Webpack chunking).

It's the opposite with `http`.